# Making downloaders register

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I'm working on a Drupal 6 site, and one of the requirements is for the company to be able to upload videos and whitepapers. No problems there.

The tricky part of the requirement is that when a site visitor tries to download one of these files, they need to be prompted to fill out a basic information form with the usual stuff; name, email address, business sector etc. If they've already done this before to download another file, then the site needs to pick up the cookie etc attached to the user and register them as downloading another file.

I've done this before on another site and it was a simple enough bunch of PHP with a database attached. I know I could easily do the same thing here, but it just doesn't feel very 'Drupal' to me.

Any Drupal-esque recommendations for the best way to tackle this (modules, plugins etc)?

Thanks

Froogle

Answer (score 1):

There are more sophisticated (and complicated) ways to accomplish it, but the following would meet your basic requirements:

1. Under *Admin > Site configuration > File system*, set the *Download method* to **Private**.
2. On the *Admin > Site building > Modules* page, enable the core Uploads module
3. On the appropriate content pages, under the *File attachments* option, upload the videos and whitepapers
4. Under *Admin > Site configuration > Error reporting*, set the *Default 403 (access denied) page* to **user/register**.

Comment: Thanks. I don't think that's going to work though since the information asked for when you register doesn't really meet all the requirements the company has. Also, I question whether we'd be able to tie up which user downloaded which file from a reporting point of view.

Comment: You can add fields to the registration page, using the core Profile module. The Download Count module would allow you to track the downloads: http://drupal.org/project/download_count